# How to add security while using GET and POST method?

Tags: php, security, post, get

I developed a small application Contact Manager and while updating the contacts, the contact id is being sent using GET method. But a user can change the Id and edit any contact, how can i add security to it?

```
<td>
    <a href="home.php?action=update&amp;contactid=<?php echo $contact->contact_id; ?>">Update</a>
</td>
```

*http://localhost/contmanager/home.php?action=update&**contactid=1***

If i change the id to some other number, another contact will show up.

Comment: Storing permissions/owner with the contact id?

Comment: i am using contact_by field which is a foreign key with refernce to user_id in users table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't control what the client asks the server to do.

If you want to add restrictions on who can modify particular contacts then you need to Authenticate (username + password, client SSL cert, OpenID, etc) users and then check if they are Authorized (this will depend on the business logic you decide on) to modify the entry in question.

Comment: i followed the solution by 'One man crew', it worked fine first time but when i try to update other contact it shows the same contact.

Comment: @MohitChawla — Of course it does, that answer is designed to only let people change the details of the logged in user. If you want to edit the *contacts of* the logged in user then you have to do what I said in this answer.

Comment: what about unset? i used unset $_SESSION['contact_id'] but it still use the same contact_id even if $_SESSION['contact_ID'] returns null when i used var_dump.

Comment: What about unset? You shouldn't be storing the contact id in the session in the first place. Store the user id in the session. Get the context id from $_POST. Check to see if the user is in the session belongs to a user who is allowed to edit the contact with the id in $_POST.

Answer (score 2):

As Quentin pointed out, your logic is going wrong here, data like these should be stored inside sessions and shouldn't be passed using `$_GET` or `$_POST`, unless and until required, if you still need to pass for some reason, than you can read my answer ahead for a solution.

Store the user id in a session, so when the user updates, just compare the session id and `$_GET` id, if it matches, update the entry else throw an error.

When the user logs in

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $db_data['col_name'];
```

Now, before the entry is updated...

```
if(!empty($_GET['user_id'])) {
  //First validate, you can check whether the id is only numeric, is valid db entry etc
  $user_id = $_GET['user_id']; //Store the id in a variable
} else {
  //Invalid
}


if($_SESSION['user_id'] == $user_id) { //Compare the ids
  //Process
} else {
  //Not Valid
}
```

> Note: Make sure you use `session_start()` at the very top of the page,
>   before you start writing anything.

Comment: There's no point in accepting the user id through POST/GET in the first place if you only ever accept one that is the same as the one in the session.

Comment: I am using register and login on this application so i can use your method but that user can also update some other contact from his own contacts by changing the id. Is there any alternative technique?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [session](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) and to store the data inside like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['contact_id']=$contact->contact_id; 
    <td><a href=home.php?action=update&amp;">Update</a></td>
?>
```

use it like this:

```
http://localhost/contmanager/home.php?action=update
```

and when you need to use contact_id(after the GET) :

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['contact_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['contact_id'])){
   $contact_id=$_SESSION['contact_id'];
  
}
```

A PHP session variable is used to store information about, or change settings for a user session. Session variables hold information about one single user, and are available to all pages in one application.

**PHP Session Variables**

When you are working with an application, you open it, do some changes and then you close it. This is much like a Session. The computer knows who you are. It knows when you start the application and when you end. But on the internet there is one problem: the web server does not know who you are and what you do because the HTTP address doesn't maintain state.

A PHP session solves this problem by allowing you to store user information on the server for later use (i.e. username, shopping items, etc). However, session information is temporary and will be deleted after the user has left the website. If you need a permanent storage you may want to store the data in a database.

Sessions work by creating a unique id (UID) for each visitor and store variables based on this UID. The UID is either stored in a cookie or is propagated in the URL.

Comment: i followd your solution but a problem occurred when tried to update another contact. it keeps showing the same contact. I used unset too but no change, i have updated code in the question.

Comment: @Mohit Chawla did you tried to set `$_SESSION['contact_id']=""` and to check if `empty($_SESSION['contact_id'])`?